# Dynamics GP - Tax Schedule ID percentages

Tags: dynamics-gp

Is there a way of getting the total tax percentage of an item's tax schedule ID?

So far all I can guess is that this can be done by getting a sum of the percentages for each tax detail ID at the taxable percentage. For instance, tax schedule ID `SP101` has three detail IDs: `S 0% OVERSEAS`, `SP101@0%` and `SP101@20%`.

`S 0% OVERSEAS` has a taxable percentage of 0% of the item, at a rate of 0%, so can be ignored.
`SP101@20%` has a taxable percentage of 67.46% of the item, at a rate of 20% and 
`SP101@0%` has a taxable percentage of 32.54% of the item, at a rate of 0%. Resulting in an overall item tax rate of 13.492% `(67.46 * 0.2) + (32.54 * 0)`.

I can probably work this out using the tax schedule master and details tables if required by expanding on the code below, but is there a way that GP does this already (for instance when calculating the tax amount of a line on a sales order) that I can use?

```
SELECT t1.TAXSCHID, t1.TXSCHDSC, t2.TAXDTLID, t2.TDTAXTAX, t3.TDTABPCT, t3.TXDTLPCT
FROM TX00101 t1
INNER JOIN TX00102 t2 ON t1.TAXSCHID = t2.TAXSCHID
INNER JOIN TX00201 t3 ON t2.TAXDTLID = t3.TAXDTLID
```

***Clarification***

Each item is assigned a tax schedule ID in the item maintenance window: in my example, this is the code `SP101`.

[image]

I want to know if there is a simple way of me finding out what tax rate (percentage) this tax schedule ID represents. The `SP101` tax schedule consists of three separate tax detail IDs, which each have their own tax rates and taxable percentages.

`S 0% OVERSEAS` has a taxable percentage of 0%, and a tax rate of 0%. So 0% of the item is taxed at a 0% rate.

[image]

`SP101@0%` has a taxable percentage of 32.54%, and a tax rate of 0%. So 32.54% of the item is taxed at a 0% rate.

[image]

`SP101@20%` has a taxable percentage of 67.46%, and a tax rate of 20%. So 67.46% of the item is taxed at a 20% rate.

[image]

Calculating the overall percentage of the tax schedule ID would just be a sum of each of the taxable percentages at their tax rates: `Tr = (0 * 0) + (32.54 * 0) + (67.46 * 0.2) = 13.492%`

The master tax schedule ID table `TX00101` contains just the description and ID without the overall tax rate for the item. Is there a table or view within Dynamics GP that will allow me to find the tax rate of a given tax schedule ID, without having to perform the above calculation to work it out manually?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  Please illustrate the problem by showing some sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the question with some additional information that I hope will provide some clarity. Thanks for looking.